# Передать тип из ViewModel для View

Tags: ios, swift, view, viewmodel

У Меня есть клас ViewModel. У меня есть два типа view которые я хочу использовать и присвоить. Каждый тип имеет свои свойстав. Например задний фон View.

```
class SomeViewModel{
    enum ViewType: Int {
        case oneViewType
        case twoViewType
    }
    //Example
      func getViewBackgroundColor() -> UIColor {
            switch ViewType {
            case .oneViewType:
                return .black
            case .twoViewType :
                return .white
            }
        }
}
```

*ViewController*

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var oneView:UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var twoView:UIView!

 var viewModel:SomeViewModel!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  //set type from viewModel for view. Something like this
  oneView.SomeViewModel.ViewType(type:oneViewType)
}
}
```

В класе SomeViewController я зделал два аутлета для View. И для каждой из этой view мне тужно передать тип из ViewModel. **Как я это могу реализовать?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых исправление

```
class SomeViewModel {
    enum ViewType: Int {
        case oneViewType
        case twoViewType
    }
    //Example
    func getViewBackgroundColor(with viewType: ViewType) -> UIColor {
        switch viewType {
        case .oneViewType:
            return .black
        case .twoViewType :
            return .white
        }
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, по существу вопроса - создаем подкласс, объявляем нужное свойство и используем его

```
class SomeView : UIView {

    var viewType: SomeViewModel.ViewType?

}
```

во вью контроллере

```
@IBOutlet weak var oneView: SomeView!

// ...

oneView.viewType = .oneViewType
```

Comment: Спасибо, переделал немного еще для себя и все работает.!